# How to prevent downloading an empty pdf file while using get and requests in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, get, python-requests

I am scraping a website which is accessible from this [link](https://bradscholars.brad.ac.uk/handle/10454/5521), using Beautiful Soup. The idea is to download all `href` that contain the string `.pdf` using the `get` module.

The code below demonstrated the procedure and is working as intended:

```
filename = 'new_name.pdf'
url_to_download_pdf='https://bradscholars.brad.ac.uk/https://www.brad.ac.uk/library/additional-help/bradford-scholars-faqs/digital_preservation_policy.pdf'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(url_to_download_pdf).content)
```

However, there is instance where the url such as given above (i.e., the variable `url_to_download_pdf`) direct to `Page not found` page. As a result, an unusable and unreadable pdf is downloaded.

Opening the file with **pdf reader** in Windows give the following warning

[image]

I am curious if there is any ways to avoid accessing and downloading an invalid `pdf` file?

Comment: you could use `if response.status_code == 404` and pass if it is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion by the user.

As per @Nicolas,

Do the save as pdf only if the response return 200

```
if response.status_code == 200:
```

In the previous version, an empty file will be created regardless of the response because following `with open(filename, 'wb') as f:` was created before the checking status_code

To mitigate this, the `with open(filename, 'wb') as f:` should be initiated only if the condition set was as intended.

The complete code then is as below:

```
import requests
filename = 'new_name.pdf'
url_to_download_pdf='https://bradscholars.brad.ac.uk/https://www.brad.ac.uk/library/additional-help/bradford-scholars-faqs/digital_preservation_policy.pdf'
my_req = requests.get(url_to_download_pdf)
if my_req.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(my_req.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly accessing the contents of the file with
`f.write(requests.get(url_to_download_pdf).content)`

You can first check the status of the request, and then if it is a valid request, then only save to file.

```py
filename = 'new_name.pdf'
url_to_download_pdf='https://bradscholars.brad.ac.uk/https://www.brad.ac.uk/library/additional-help/bradford-scholars-faqs/digital_preservation_policy.pdf'
response = requests.get(url_to_download_pdf)
if(response.status_code != 404):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to validate that the file you request for, already exists. If the file exists, the **response code** of the request will be **200**. So here an example of how to do that:

```
filename = 'new_name.pdf'
url_to_download_pdf='https://bradscholars.brad.ac.uk/https://www.brad.ac.uk/library/additional-help/bradford-scholars-faqs/digital_preservation_policy.pdf'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    response = requests.get(url_to_download_pdf)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        f.write(response.content)
    else:
        print("Error, the file doesn't exist")
```